# xaml set value of ResourceDictionary entry to the value of another entry in the resource in the dictionary

Tags: maui

I have what I think is a simple problem here, but cannot find any documentation on how to do this.

I have a resource dictionary and want to be able to set one value to be equal to another item in the dictionary. For example:

```
<x:String x:Key="MyMapPin">&#xf276;</x:String>
<x:String x:Key="MyIconPickup">{?? MyMapPin}</x:String>
<x:String x:Key="MyIconDestination">{?? MyMapPin}</x:String>
```

Is there any way to make both MyIconPickup and MyIconDestination equal the value of MyMapPin?

(edit due to unhelpful comment)
The reason I want to do this is because, in this example, MyIconPickup or MyIconDestination may be required, at some point in the future, to deviate from the MyMapPin. Therefore I don't want to have to hunt down all instances of the icon and then change it again.

Alternatively I may NOT wish to change the MyIconPickup or MyIconDestination, but I may wish to change all of the icons that derive from MyMapPin. This is basic inheritance...

Comment: Its best to make one generically named resource and simply reuse that one

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to do it in XAML. Do it in c# code behind:

```cs
InitializeComponent();

// ASSUMES in XAML, you've given resource dictionary x:Name="myDictionary".
myDictionary["MyIconPickup"] = myDictionary["MyMapPin"];
```